# Iterate the creation of a HashMap as a value in another HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, loops

I have a HashMap with a key as an object of some class, and a value as another HashMap, who's key is a String, and value is a Double:

```
HashMap<MyClass, HashMap<String, Double>> myHashMap;
```

I need a loop that will add keys (objects) and values (HashMaps) to this HashMap, but I cannot create a new HashMap variable in the loop as its 'value'. Essentially, every MyClass object must have Strings with corresponding Doubles.

Is this possible? Does this even make any sense??

Comment: Yeah it is possible, but show us what you have tried.

Comment: Wait, you said your HashMap has `String` as key, but you are using `Object`. And if you have `String` with corresponding `Double` for an `Object`, then why don't you create a `HashMap<String, List<YourClass>>`?

Comment: Sorry, the Key is indeed an Object of a custom class

Comment: @Frisky.. Then probably your data structure is built wrongly. You should have `String` as `key`, `List<YourClassObject>` as value. I'll post an answer.

Comment: If you can use third party libraries, you might find Guava's [`Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) more appropriate than nested maps.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
YourClass someObject = new YourClass();
//putting object to map with empty hashMap value
myHashMap.put(someObject, new HashMap<String,Double>());
//adding String,Double to created before hashMap value
myHashMap.get(someObject).put("PI", 3.14);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like:

```
    Object objectKey;
    String stringKey;
    Double value;
     .
     .
     .

    loop

    if(!myHashMap.containsKey(objectKey)){
        myHashMap.put(objectKey, new HashMap<String, Double>());
    }

    HashMap<String, Double> accordingHashMap = myHashMap.get(objectKey);

    accordingHashMap.put(stringKey, value)

    endloop
```